# Probability of finding less than 2 defective products

Tags: probability

My Approach: 
If 100 are produced 2 light bulbs will be defective.

In 10 cases (10 lightbulbs each); we have a 50% chance that the 2 will be in 1 box and a 50% chance that 2 defectives will be in 2 boxes. 
Therefore the probability of it failing its guarantee is (1/10)(1/2)= 5%

Is this correct? I am not sure how else to approach this problem.

Comment: "My Approach: If 100 are produced 2 light bulbs will be defective. " You cant assume that, there might be 3 light bulbs defective in 100, or all 100 might be defective. Hint: This looks like a good spot for a binomial distribution.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:$P(x \geq 2) = 1 - P(x < 2) = 1 - P(x = 0) - P(x = 1) = 1 - \binom{10}{0}(0.02)^0\cdot (0.98)^{10} - \binom{10}{1}(0.02)^1\cdot 0.98^{9}$. Can you work out the details?

Comment: How do i account for the 10 light bulbs per case?

Comment: My answer is good for any "$10$ bulbs"

Answer (score 0):

You want 1 minus the probability that at most one bulb is defective.

The probability that none of the 10 bulbs are defective is $(1-0.02)^{10}=(0.98)^{10}$ assuming independence. The probability that 1 bulb of 10 is defective is $10\times (0.98)^9 \times (0.02)$

You need to add these and subtract from 1.

In general, probability that at most $\ell$ of $n$ items are defective when each is independently defective with probability $p$ is
$$
\sum_{0\leq k \leq \ell} \binom{n}{k}p^k (1-p)^{n-k}
$$
whihch is known as the binomial distribution

Comment: How do i account for the 10 light bulbs per case (10 cases)?